# How to populate two separate lists using two separate list comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing code to populate two columns from a CSV file (`row[0]` and `row[1]`) using a list comprehension (`transaction_list` and `revenue_list`, respectively) in Python 3.6.3.

If I run the **code below**, I can get the script to populate `revenue_list` properly, but `transaction_list` will return an empty list.

```
import os, csv
csvpath = os.path.join('budget_data_1.csv')

with open(csvpath) as f:
   readcsv = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

   next(readcsv)

   revenue_list = [int(row[1]) for row in readcsv]
   print(revenue_list)

   transaction_list = [row[0] for row in readcsv]
   print(transaction_list)
```

On the other hand, if I run the **code below** (which comments out `revenue_list = [int(row[1]) for row in readcsv]`), I can get `transaction_list` to return the correct list.

```
import os, csv
csvpath = os.path.join('budget_data_1.csv')

with open(csvpath) as f:
   readcsv = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

   next(readcsv)

   #revenue_list = [int(row[1]) for row in readcsv]
   #print(revenue_list)

   transaction_list = [row[0] for row in readcsv]
   print(transaction_list)
```

**Question:**  Why does the script return `transaction_list` as an empty list when I attempt to populate `transaction_list` *and* `revenue_list` as written?

Comment: Because `readcsv` is an iterator that will be consumed once you iterated over it once.

Comment: `readcsv` is an iterator that is extinguished after the first iteration.

Comment: After the first read, call `f.seek(0)` to reset the file pointer.

Comment: Make a list containing both things in a tuple. You could then process it again to get two separate lists for each parameter. Assuming its not huge.